# Kill a job in Bash Script

Tags: bash, kill

I have bash script which calls a number of commands including the TOP command.
My question is how do I kill the TOP command programmatically and pass control back to the script so it can continue to run?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do this in the same script or another script? You can't do it in the same script, because the script doesn't continue until `top` exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the script to start `top` in the foreground just for some time, use the `timeout` command :

```
timeout --foreground 30s top
```

to run top for 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Use the iteration option `-n number` in combination with `-d delay`.

```
top -d2 -n10
```

... will do the job about 18 seconds plus some more (time between first and last = 9*2s + execution time).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what for you start `top` in the first place from a script if you want to kill it without user interaction moments later. Perhaps it would be sufficient to start the `top` and detach it, using `&` operator, so your script is not blocked:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "before"
top &
echo "after"
```